# Eugene and big number Code Chef: KBIGNUMB

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to submit my code (python) for below problem in codechef

https://www.codechef.com/problems/KBIGNUMB

The code works fine but when I submit it, the testing tool rejects it since execution takes more than 4 seconds. How do I make my code faster

My code is available in below link

https://repl.it/IeBf/39

Comment: Think about a better algorithm, maybe?

Comment: Look up some basic information about big-O notation and algorithmic performance. Choosing the wrong approach can be exponentially slower for code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions  @Michael shopsin and Artur R. Czechowski